# Networkdrive Issue - Missing in Explorer but not in e.g. Office

Tags: windows-explorer, microsoft-office, network-drive, windows-server-2012, save-as

### Related posts:

[Mapped network drive missing from My Computer and Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/147033/mapped-network-drive-missing-from-my-computer-and-explorer)

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/101980-network-drives-not-showing-in-explorer-but-show-up-in-excel-and-word

### Problem:

Networkdrives are randomly hiding in explorer but in Office under "Save as" all networkdrives are shown correctly.

### Environment:

It is an citrix environment with 4 Windows 2012 terminal-servers. There are about 200 users working on these servers. All users are using roaming profiles with many different networkdrive assignments. The networkdrives are connected with group policies. The problem exists in different OUs with different GPOs about networkdrives.

### Known, functional workaround:

- Restart explorer on terminal session - This will show the networkdrives again

### What we have tested

- There are no entries in the eventlog on terminalservers or fileserver
- Connection networkdrives manually / with script (persistent: yes)
- All Updates are installed

-

Hopefully somebody can help us :'(

Thanks in advance and kind regards

manawel

Comment: maybe the impact of UAC:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035277/en-us

Comment: The problem just appeared again. This wasnt the solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I maybe do have the solution. Since one week the drives did not dissapear again.
All I have done is I changed the GPOs a little.

While the problem appeared we connected the networkdrives with the option "Replace" in GPO. Now I changed it to "Update" and the problem seems to be gone. If not, I will note it here.

Hopefully this helps someone with a similar problem.

Regards
Manawel